# PowerShell updating a csv file based from a csv file as a source

Tags: powershell, csv

I am new to PowerShell or any scripting stuff.

I have here a DataResources(CSV File) which contains of bunch of data's that needs to be inserted into a Results.CSV

Here is my DataResources

[image]

For my Result.csv looks like this.

[image]

My goal is to export a NEW csv file based from a results.csv as a template
and if a HostName/Host match the data contains a value equivalent to UA and PWD will be inserted/updated from ExportResources CSV file to Exported new CSV File

after executing scripts that I have created it only modifies 1 row not all.

[image]

This is what I've done so far.

```
    $DataSource = Import-Csv -Path D:\coding\Powershell\csv\Resources\ExportResources.csv
$DataResults = Import-Csv -Path D:\coding\Powershell\csv\Result\results.csv


foreach ($ItemDataResults in $DataResults) 
{
    $HostName = $ItemDataResults.HostName
    $UA = $ItemDataResults.UA
    $PASSWD = $ItemDataResults.PWD

}

$ItemDataSource = $DataSource | ? {$_.Host -eq $HostName}
if ($UA -eq "" -and $PASSWD -eq "")
{
    $ItemDataResults.UA = $ItemDataSource.UA
    $ItemDataResults.PWD = $ItemDataSource.Passwd

} 



$DataResults | Export-Csv D:\coding\Powershell\csv\new.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The result almost meet my expectation but the problem here that it only fills one hostname the rest are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your script is that you loop through `$DataResults` once, but you have to iterate through it once for each item in `$DataSource` if you use the method that you're employing. I believe that a better method is to create a hashtable from one CSV, using the host name as the key, and the whole object as the value, then loop through the second array updating the value for each host. That would look something like this:

```
$DataSource = Import-Csv -Path D:\coding\Powershell\csv\Resources\ExportResources.csv
$DataResults = Import-Csv -Path D:\coding\Powershell\csv\Result\results.csv

$DataHT = @{}
$DataResults | ForEach-Object { $DataHT.Add($_.HostName,$_) }

ForEach( $Record in $DataSource ){
    $DataHT[$Record.Host].UA = $Record.UA
    $ItemDataResults.PWD = $Record.Passwd
} 



$DataHT.Values | Export-Csv D:\coding\Powershell\csv\new.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi Thanks,

it resolves my problem.